# Recursive tar compression?

Tags: command-line, tar

I'd like to create a tar file to compress a folder that contains sub folders. I'm trying with the following command int in the terminal:

```
tar -czf folder directorios.tar.gz
```

directorios.tar.gz would be the result

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Try:

```
tar -czvf directorios.tar.gz folder
```

A few notes:

1. Recursion is *the default*, from the `tar` man pages:

   ```
   -c, --create
       Create a new archive.  Arguments supply the names of the files to be archived.
       Directories  are  archived  recursively,  unless  the --no-recursion option is
       given.
   ```

   Although this can be turned off by using the `--no-recursion` option...
2. You need the archive name *immediately after* the `-f` option, the correct sequence being:

   ```
   tar -c [-f ARCHIVE] [OPTIONS] [FILE...]
            ^^^^^^^^^^
   ```
3. For a more *flexible* command line (particularly if you wanted to use other compression utilities apart from gzip with tar) you could omit the `-z` option and use `-a` or `--auto-compress` option to allow tar to *automatically* decide which compressor to use based on the archive *suffix*:

   ```
   -a, --auto-compress
       Use archive suffix to determine the compression program.
   ```

   Recognised suffixes (and their attendant compressing applications) are:

   - .gz : gzip
   - .tgz : gzip
   - .taz : gzip
   - .z : compress
   - .taZ : compress
   - .bz2 : bzip2
   - .tz2 : bzip2
   - .tbz2 : bzip2
   - .tbz : bzip2
   - .lz : lzip
   - .lzma : lzma
   - .tlz : lzma
   - .lzo : lzop
   - .xz : xz
   - .zst : zstd
   - .tzst : zstd

tar is pretty cool :)

**References:**

- [8.1.1 Creating and Reading Compressed Archives](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/gzip.html) Sound information on using the auto-compress options with tar as well as the possibilities for accomplishing the same goal with a more manual and flexible option...

Comment: Is directorios.tar.gz a gzip tarfile? I have red that -cz creates a gzip and -v(verbose) shows the process.

Comment: @sam Indeed, my apologies, I have added this in. You could omit the `-z` option and use `-a` to allow tar to guess from the archive suffix....

Comment: @sam OK I have bulked up the answer considerably, hopefully some useful additions in there for you :)

Comment: I used both `-z` and `-a` and didn't notice any difference(i'm working on a remote server). Both tars weight the same. In the exercise I'm asked to create a gzip, then decompress it using  gunzip. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: **Add date&time&timezone to the zip file name** `tar -zcf "yourzipname_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S%z(%Z)').tar.gz" your_source_folder`  the `+` is just a "start of the format"), I've also removed the `v` if you don't need "verbose" output which mainly outputs ALL files being added x)